# Xamarin.Android rounded background circle around text

Tags: xml, xamarin.android, textview

I would like to have a red circle around text. Example below the red circle around the white text number 2.

[image]

I am able to make it a red background, but its a square instead of a circle/oval. Its also further away then I would like.

[image]

I know in CSS you can use border-radius and left to get it to be an oval and be closer. But I cant seem to get the same in this .axml. I see some articles mention Shape, but im not sure if a textview can be inside of this, and also if it can be accessed programmatically (display or not display based on a condition)

.**axml**:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="2" >

            <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgPPhoto"
                        android:src="@drawable/p_circle"
                        style="@style/EImageView.Icon"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp" 
                        />
                <TextView   
                            android:id="@+id/txtActiveVCount"
                            style="@style/ETextView.Heading"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:background="#CF1B00"
                            android:paddingLeft="-0.5rem"
                            />

                <TextView   
                            android:id="@+id/txtPName"
                            style="@style/ETextView.Heading"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center" />
            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>              
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks a bit ovalish now

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Android Layout` type file named "circle.xml" in drawable folder with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       >
    <solid android:color="#FFF44444"/>
    <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

layout.xml: Add `android:background="@drawable/circle"` to TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ss"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="5"
                  android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                  android:background="@drawable/circle"/>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I saw some other solutions I saw had something similar but the shape was in the activities axml and the textview indented. This was different since it set the background to the shape. The shape was added to the drawable resources. Thanks again!

Comment: Btw is there a way to make it more circular? It looks a little more like an oval. Ive tried changing the width and radius but it does not seem to have an affect.

Comment: @angleUr I found a post. There are new ideas: Use the native ImageView and create a circular bitmap to set its android: src and use android: background. You can just add square measurements for your image view, and it will appear as a circle. That means assigning the same width and height.

Comment: The problem with an image is, I need to have a number that is generated from the code behind that shows in the circle. So I dont think that would work with an imageview since it needs to be dynamic.